# Условие выбора категорий

Tags: java, android, google-maps

У меня есть фрагмент со списком категорий:

```
 private void initializeData() {
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("category1", "Первая", R.drawable.category1));
        persons.add(new Person("category2", "Вторая", R.drawable.category2));
        persons.add(new Person("category3", "Третья", R.drawable.category3));
    }
```

По нажатию на какую то из категорий перехожу в активность, где у меня содержится карта, содержащая в себе маркеры с их значениями(название, координаты).
Так как у меня все мои категории содержат карту, но с разными значениями маркеров хочу попробовать реализовать всё в одной активити.

То есть, нажимая на категорию мы переходим в активити, передавая ей определенные параметры этой категории(например местоположения пекарнь). Активити в свою очередь ***должна*** получить параметры и ***определить*** для какой категории нужно отобразить маркеры(должна отобразить маркеры пекарнь, а не библиотек).

На данный момент передаю для каждую активность следующим образом:

```
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    Marker Pekarnea= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.045029, 28.861427))
            .title("Marker"));
    Marker Biblioteka= map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.000327, 28.867950))
            .title("Marker"));
    Marker marker3 = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(47.024204, 28.889236))
            .title("Marker"));

    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker2.getPosition());
    builder.include(marker3.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: `как реализовать в одной активности - условие выбора категорий` – вот с этого места нужно поподробнее. Вам необходимо в активити передать `persons` или?

Comment: Изначально нужно передать параметры в активити после чего в конечной активити в зависимости от пришедшего параметра отображать нужные маркера для конкретной категории.
Возможно лучше как то передавать ID категории.

Comment: @post_zeew вопрос некорректно задан?

Comment: Насчет корректности ничего сказать не могу, но вопроса в целом я не понял, это да.

Comment: @post_zeew обновил вопрос.

Comment: В активити можно дополнительно передать категорию.

Comment: @post_zeew а зачем? когда я и так передаю туда несколько категорий в методе `initializeData`.

Comment: В методе `initializeData()` Вы ничего никуда не передаете.

Comment: @post_zeew вы правы, я по нажатию на категорию просто перехожу в категорию `intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MapActivity.class);` к примеру. Категорию передать с помощью putExtra?

Comment: Да, наверное, можно и так.

Comment: Посмотрите, как устроен стартовый шаблон *Master - Detail Fow* в Android studio, там как раз реализован механизм отображения разных данных в одной активити в зависимости от переданного значения.